# Have Context Menu close on mouseclick outside C#

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a listener on the mouse right click event that fires off `CreateContextMenu()`

The function looks like this:

```
protected virtual ContextMenu CreateContextMenu()
    {
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        MenuItem ClickHereMenuItem = new MenuItem();
        ClickHereMenuItem.Header = "Click Here";
        ClickHereMenuItem.Tag = contextMenu;
        ClickHereMenuItem.Click += ClickHere_Click;

        contextMenu.Items.Add(ClickHereMenuItem);

        contextMenu.Items.Add(new Separator());

        //Cancel Menu Item
        MenuItem cancelMenuItem = new MenuItem();
        cancelMenuItem.Header = "Cancel";
        cancelMenuItem.Tag = contextMenu;
        cancelMenuItem.Click += cancelMenuItem_Click;

        contextMenu.Items.Add(cancelMenuItem);
        return contextMenu; 
    }
```

Everything works as intended, but the only way the context menu closes is if you select the 'Cancel' menu item (which just sets `contextMenu.IsOpen = false`). I also want the menu to close if the user click outside of the Control.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What GUI r u using? Windows forms?

Comment: i cannot reproduce your problem : with your code, my context menu closes ok.
So the issue must be in your PreviewMouse(Left)ButtonDown or elsewhere.

Comment: @mhn I'm using a WPF GUI

Comment: So clicking outside of a `System.Windows.Control.ContextMenu` to close it is default functionality?  Why is this not working then? I'm not overloading anything except OnRightMouseclick..

Comment: overloading OnRightMouseClick ???
you mean adding an event handler to OnRightMouseClick, no ?
(you must have some very good reasons to overload instead of just adding event handler for a case that seems simple so far.)

Comment: Oops. Yes, I meant adding an even handler :)

Comment: I have no reply, but a piece of advice : create brand new project and just ('unit') test your feature (don't forget to put transparent background to catch RightMouseClick :=) ) , making your project looking more and more like the real one  until it breaks in the same way. Because for sure just this piece of code works.

Answer (score 0):

Try dispose method to close it

```
.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Canvas layout with the height and width occupying ur app window size, set its visibility to hide and then add the context menu as a child to the canvas. Now you can handle the MouseLeftButtonDown event of canvas and set the contextMenu.IsOpen = false in that. Now this canvas occupies the entire working area of ur app, so where ever the right clicks u can open the context menu and where ever user left clicks the context menu can be closed.

This is the way the popup, context menus etc., works in windows and web apps.

Code looks similar to this,

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Height = Application.Height; //replace with ur app height
canvas.Width = Application.Width; //replace with ur app width
canvas.Child(ContextMenu); 
canvas.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s,e) => { contextMenu.IsOpen = false};
```

This is not the actual code, use it as a reference.